# Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, json.net

```
var stringResult = {"reporting":{"default":{"Outpatient":8045376.0,"OutpatientPMPM":101.6472,"totalWorkersCompClaimsPaid":7718428.46,"totalWorkersCompClaimsPaidPMPM":97.5165,"totalMedicalPaidAmount":1.6883294E7,"totalMedicalPaidAmountPMPM":213.3076,"totalVisionClaimsPaid":2837.69,"totalVisionClaimsPaidPMPM":0.0359,"totalPharmacyPaidAmount":2.478251486E7,"totalPharmacyPaidAmountPMPM":313.1082,"totalDentalClaimsPaid":12271.67,"totalDentalClaimsPaidPMPM":0.155,"employeeMonths":35415.0,"memberMonths":79150.0,"subscribers":3009.0,"totalVendorPaidAmount":97034.0,"totalVendorPaidAmountPMPM":1.226,"Office":4285314.0,"OfficePMPM":54.1417,"Inpatient":4552604.0,"InpatientPMPM":57.5187,"members":6741.0,"totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid":4.949638068000001E7,"averageFamilySize":2.2403,"totalHealthPlanClaimsPaidPMPM":625.3492}}}

dynamic json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringResult);
float value = json.reporting.@default.totalPharmacyPaidAmount;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> page in json.reporting.@default)
{
    var key = page.Key;
    var totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid = page.Value.totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid;
    var averageFamilySize = page.Value.averageFamilySize;
}
```

I am getting an error in foreach loop as

> Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'.

while performing the above task where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It is already kind of telling you what the issue is. `json.reporting.@default` returns a `JProperty`, not a `KeyValuePair`. Maybe execute your code in a debugger and take a look at the object returned by `json.reporting.@default` so you'll get an idea of the object and data returned and how you can use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json.reporting.@default returns Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty, change your code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> page in json.reporting.@default.Children())
{
    var key = page.Key;
    var totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid = page.Value.totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid;
    var averageFamilySize = page.Value.averageFamilySize;
}
```

docs for read about it http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm

Answer (score 2):

What @progpow said is right. You can also convert the result set into a dictionary and iterate through it.

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> result = json.reporting.@default.ToObject<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,dynamic> page in result)
{
  var key = page.Key;
    var totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid = page.Value.totalHealthPlanClaimsPaid;
    var averageFamilySize = page.Value.averageFamilySize;
}
```